# Загрузка фотографии VK (php)

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Доброго всем дня!

В `$photos` хранится строка с фото.

При выводе на экран через `echo` выводит правильно:

```
'file1' => '@/var/www/xdrent/data/www/test.biz/upload/lexx/25397178_118034/089dd91706ec5a801102fc.jpg','file2' => '@/var/www/xdrent/data/www/test.biz/upload/lexx/25397178_118034/40fc3c94aec04cde3fa9b8.jpg','file3' => '@/var/www/xdrent/data/www/test.biz/upload/lexx/25397178_118034/1edb44ca42ad51597678a2.jpg','file4' => '@/var/www/xdrent/data/www/test.biz/upload/lexx/25397178_118034/f9cbf3efd9a00b1f0fbb6b.jpg'
```

Далее отправляю

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $VKuploadUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  array($photos)); 
$otvet = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

и в ответ `[photo] => []`

а если

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $VKuploadUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  array('file1' => '@/var/www/xdrent/data/www/test.biz/upload/lexx/25397178_118034/089dd91706ec5a801102fc.jpg','file2' => '@/var/www/xdrent/data/www/test.biz/upload/lexx/25397178_118034/40fc3c94aec04cde3fa9b8.jpg','file3' => '@/var/www/xdrent/data/www/test.biz/upload/lexx/25397178_118034/1edb44ca42ad51597678a2.jpg','file4' => '@/var/www/xdrent/data/www/test.biz/upload/lexx/25397178_118034/f9cbf3efd9a00b1f0fbb6b.jpg')); 
$otvet = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

То отправляет ок

В чем проблема?

Comment: Массив массивов? Не шутите?

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $photos); - ?

Comment: 1. Так вы посмотрите, что вы отправляет в каждом случае - в первом случае вы отправляете массив из одной строки (причем это НЕ валидная картинка), во втором же случае вы отправляете массив валидных картинок.

2. А зачем все ручками делать? SDK не пробовали использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените строку:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  array($photos));
```

на строку:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $photos);
```

И все будет работать!

**UPD**
Как я понял, переменная `$photos` у Вас строка, по этой причине у Вас код и не работает. Вам надо на стадии формирования путей к картинкам записывать их в массив.
Я так понимаю, у тебя идет цикл по вытягиванию картинок из БД.

```
//Начало цикла
$photos['file'.$i] = 'ПУТЬ ДО КАРТИНКИ';
//Конец цикла
```

**UPD2**

**Правильный код:**

```
$photos = array();

for ($k = 0; $k < count($wall[$i]->attachments); $k++) {

 $nom = $k + 1;

 $photos['file'.$nom] = '@' . $dir . $newfile;    
}
```

И после чего используете строку: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $photos);`.

Comment: ( не хочет

Comment: Если $photos строка, то конечно не будет работать

Comment: На стадии формирования строки, тебе надо формировать массив!
И потом передать его так, как я написал выше

Comment: Извиняюсь за наглость, можно пример.  
Я пытаюсь так:
  
    for ($k = 0; $k < count($wall[$i]->attachments); $k++) {
    $nom = $k + 1;
     $photos .= "'file".$nom."' => '@".$dir.$newfile."',";
    }

Comment: Написал, смотри UPD2. Если ответ правильный, то не забудь его отметить как правильный!

Comment: Ну что, работает?

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Работает

Answer (score 0):

$photos - строка или массив? Массивы через echo не выводятся, по-моему.

Comment: Опечатался  Строка